# How to get exact time required for calling each of the partlerlink of a composite instance

Tags: oracle11g, soa, bpel

I have a requirement to get time elapsed for calling each of the partnerlink in the BPEL given a particular composite instance ID.

For example,if in my code I am using two partner links

- BIService
- PGP encryption
- DB procedure call.

I need to show how much time was required while invoking BI,PGP service and DB procedure call separately in a dashboard.

I am using java facade API for accessing SOA instance details.
I am not able to find exact which classes n methods to use for my specified requirement.
I am using SOA 11g.